# specifying custom partition and clustering keys when creating vertices with gremlin-python

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, gremlinpython

I have created the following schema using a custom partition and clustering key:

```
schema.propertyKey('_partition').Text().create()
schema.propertyKey('topic_id').Uuid().create()
schema.vertexLabel('custom_topic')
    .partitionKey('_partition').clusteringKey('topic_id').create()
```

I can now create vertices using gremlin in the following way:

```
graph.addVertex(label, 'custom_topic', '_partition', 'my_partition', 'topic_id', '60bcae02-f6e5-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66')
```

However, our application is written in python using aiogremlin, and gremlin-python does not provide this graph interface. We can use a traversal to add vertices instead:

```
g.addV(label, 'custom_topic', '_partition', 'x', 'topic_id', '60bcae02-f6e5-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66')
```

The above works in DSE Studio. However, using gremlin-python it does *not* work, returning the following error:

```
aiogremlin.exception.GremlinServerError: 500: 599: Could not locate method: GraphTraversalSource.addV([label, custom_topic, _partition, x, topic_id, 60bcae02-f6e5-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66])
```

DSE reports a `DeserialisationError`. I tried to pass the keys via `properties` several different ways:

```
g.addV('custom_topic').properties('_partition', 'x', 'topic_id', '60bcae02-f6e5-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66')
GremlinServerError: 500: 599: Vertices with custom IDs must have their IDs specified on creation.

g.addV('custom_topic').property(T.id, ['_partition', 'x', 'topic_id', '60bcae02-f6e5-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66'])
GremlinServerError: 500: 500: Vertex does not support user supplied identifiers
```

How should I pass these IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting this question I've found the magic incantation that allows this to work. The key is to specify each property in a separate call:

```
g.addV('custom_topic').property('_partition', 'x').property('custom_topic', '60bcae02-f6e5-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66')
```

I do not know why `properties` does not work, but there it is.